# WPF Theme Error: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path

Tags: wpf, themes

I'm getting a weird error on a WPF theme: `Cannot resolve all property references in the property path '(0).(1).(2)[0].X'`
I've traced it down to my progress bar theming.

```
    <Style x:Key="ProgressBarStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="6" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:.5"
                                                     From="0"
                                                     To="20"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.Transform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].X"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateGradientFill" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ProgressBarTrack"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track"
                               Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                    <Decorator x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Foreground">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator"
                                       Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Decorator>
                    <Grid x:Name="IndeterminateRoot"
                          Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateSolidFill"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                   Opacity="1"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   StrokeThickness="0" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateGradientFill"
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndeterminateBackgroundBrush}"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                   StrokeThickness="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                             Value="Vertical">
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform"
                                TargetName="TemplateRoot">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                TargetName="Indicator"
                                Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                TargetName="IndeterminateRoot"
                                Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate"
                             Value="false">
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarBackgroundBrush"
                 Color="{StaticResource Color_005}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarForegroundBrush"
                 Color="{StaticResource Color_024}" />
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateBackgroundBrush"
                     EndPoint="0,1"
                     MappingMode="Absolute"
                     SpreadMethod="Repeat"
                     StartPoint="20,1"
                     Opacity="0.8">
    <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform X="0" />
            <SkewTransform AngleX="-30" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color_023}"
                  Offset="0.249" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color_024}"
                  Offset=".25" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color_024}"
                  Offset="0.75" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Color_023}"
                  Offset="0.751" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Now from what I can see, its the `DoubleAnimation.Storyboard.TargetProperty` and the reference to the `LinearGradientBrush ProgressBarIndeterminateBackgroundBrush`'s transforms.  But it looks 'ok' to my noob understanding of this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your situation and simply changing `(Shape.Fill)` to `(Rectangle.Fill)` seems to solve the problem for me.

Comment: The progress bar works when running, but VS2010 is still whinging about the error.  Do you know what that type of referencing used in the animation part is?  I've not see that used before.